# I want to join two aggregrated result sets

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is to get sum of total qty and sum of total returned qty. I got the answers individually but need help to combine.

```
SELECT c.city_name
      ,pc.prod_cat_name
      ,TO_CHAR(th.txn_date, 'w')
      ,TO_CHAR(th.txn_date, 'yyyy')
      ,SUM(td.qty)
  FROM city      c
      ,prod_cat  pc
      ,product   p
      ,txn_hdr   th
      ,txn_det   td
      ,store_det s
      ,state     st
 WHERE c.state_id = st.state_id
   AND s.city_id = c.city_id
   AND s.store_id = th.store_idand th.txn_hdr_id = td.txn_hdr_id
   AND td.prod_id = p.prod_id
   AND p.prod_cat_id = pc.prod_cat_id
 GROUP BY c.city_name
         ,pc.prod_cat_name
         ,TO_CHAR(th.txn_date, 'w')
         ,TO_CHAR(th.txn_date, 'yyyy')
```

Output

```
Bangalore   Electronics 1   2015    1
Bangalore   Electronics 3   2015    1
Bangalore   Clothing    2   2015    1
Bangalore   Clothing    1   2015    2
Chennai     Stationary  1   2015    10
Chennai     Cars_bike   4   2015    5
Bangalore   Clothing    3   2015    4
```

Second query

```
SELECT c.city_name
      ,pc.prod_cat_name
      ,TO_CHAR(th.txn_date, 'ww')
      ,TO_CHAR(th.txn_date, 'yyyy')
      ,SUM(returned_qty)
  FROM city       c
      ,prod_cat   pc
      ,store_det  st
      ,txn_hdr    th
      ,txn_det    td
      ,product    p
      ,return_hdr rh
      ,return_det rd
 WHERE th.txn_hdr_id = td.txn_hdr_id
   AND th.store_id = st.store_id
   AND st.city_id = c.city_id
   AND td.prod_id = p.prod_id
   AND p.prod_cat_id = pc.prod_cat_id
   AND rh.txn_hdr_id = th.txn_hdr_id
   AND rh.return_hdr_id = rd.ret_hdr_id
 GROUP BY c.city_name
         ,pc.prod_cat_name
         ,TO_CHAR(th.txn_date, 'ww')
         ,TO_CHAR(th.txn_date, 'yyyy')
```

Output

```
Bangalore   Clothing    37  2015    1 
Bangalore   Electronics 28  2015    1
```

I want one table with total qty and total returned qty..

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) At the very least, you can try using those queries as subqueries to get the result: `select ... from (select ...) as a join (select ...) as b on ...`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
SELECT c.city_name, pc.prod_cat_name,
       TO_CHAR (th.txn_date, 'w') wom,
       TO_CHAR (th.txn_date, 'yyyy') yr,
       SUM (td.qty) qty,
       NULL woy, 
       NULL rqty
FROM ...
UNION
SELECT c.city_name, pc.prod_cat_name,
       NULL wom,
       TO_CHAR (th.txn_date, 'yyyy') yr,
       NULL qty,
       TO_CHAR (th.txn_date, 'ww') woy,
       SUM (returned_qty) rqty
FROM ...
```

Comment: I will check for the output... But the question was like get me the total qty purchased and total returned qty --- Prod cat wise, week and year wise

Comment: Please help, the output is like this --

Bangalore Electronics 28 2015 1 1
Chennai Stationary 40 2015 10 
Bangalore Clothing 38 2015 4 
Bangalore Electronics 28 2015 1 
Bangalore Clothing 31 2015 2 
Chennai Cars_bike 39 2015 5 
Bangalore Clothing 37 2015 1 1
Bangalore Electronics 40 2015 1 
Bangalore Clothing 37 2015 1 

Group by function is not applying to this output

Comment: It is still not clear what kind of results you want.
The output what you wrote contains only 6 out of 7 columns
The columns are:
CityName, ProductName,  weekOfMonth, Year,  QTY, weekOfYear, RQTY.  
Please make a result table that includes the column names, and only those values which are written in the example.